# Не подключается jquery через webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

Подскажите как подключить jquery используя webpack.
Я сделал следующее:

1) Скачал jQuery и положил в директорию Lib:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Настроил вебпак:

```
"use strict"
{
    let path = require('path');
    const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
    const bundleFolder = "wwwroot/bundle/";

    module.exports = {
        entry: "./Scripts/main.ts",


        output: {
            filename: 'script.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, bundleFolder)
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    loader: "ts-loader",
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                },
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
        },
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin([bundleFolder]),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: "./Lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js",
                jquery: "./Lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js",
                "windows.jQuery": "./Lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js",
            })
        ],

        devtool: "inline-source-map"
    };
}
```

Вот мой файл индекса:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="helloworld"></h1>
    <div class="test">123</div>

    <script src="~/bundle/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Основной скрипт:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

$(".test").css("background", "yellow");
```

(не знаю для чего я пишу import, вроде должно без него но IDE подчеркивает красным если убираю)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю как это работает, если вы хотите подключить jQuery к проекту то его необходимо добавить в граф зависимостей

`npm i jquery -D`

И в `webpack.config.js` добавить что то вроде такого

```
....
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery"
}),
....
```

И тогда Webpack будет автоматически подключать jquery при встрече `$` или `jQuery`